# C++ POCO - How to beautify a JSON?

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries

I generate a `JSON` file using `POCO` library like this:

```
void writeToFile()
{
    Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr json = new Poco::JSON::Object;
    json->set("name", "foo");
    json->set("address", "bar");

    std::ostringstream oss;
    Poco::JSON::Stringifier::stringify(json, oss);
    std::ofstream ofs("output.json");
    if (ofs.is_open() == true)
    {
        ofs << oss.str();
        ofs.close();
    }
}
```

The `output.json` contains:

```
{"name":"foo","address":"bar"}
```

Is there any way on `POCO` to beautify a `JSON`?

So that the output would be like:

```
{
    "name" : "foo",
    "address" : "bar"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with `indent` and `step` arguments of `stringify()`?

Comment: wow!! sorry about that, I completely missed it. Can you write that on the answers so I can close this question?:)

Comment: I don't want to write an answer without testing it myself and I don't have time today. Feel free to self-answer. Have an nice day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Dmitry said on the comments, the parameters on the `stringify()` method would do:

```
static void stringify(
    const Dynamic::Var & any,
    std::ostream & out,
    unsigned int indent = 0,
    int step = - 1,
    int options = Poco::JSON_WRAP_STRINGS
);
```

Example:

```
Poco::JSON::Stringifier::stringify(json, oss, 4, -1, Poco::JSON_PRESERVE_KEY_ORDER);
```